# extern declaration of array

Tags: c99, extern, variable-declaration

I have an array with size determined during compile-time defined in a source file.

```
const int array[] = {1, 3, 3, 7};
```

The number of the elements could change in the future so I'd rather not hardcode it in the brackets.

This array needs to be accessed from several source files so I'm trying to add an extern declaration to it in a header. However I'm not sure this is possible due to the implicit array size. I tried two variants:

```
extern const int array[]; // Warning: size of symbol `array' changed from 8 to 16
extern const int *array; // error: conflicting types for 'array'
```

Is it possible to do this or should I look for a work-around?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the header that declares the variable, write:

```
extern const int array[];
```

You're right, though, that the other files won't know the size of the array.  That's trickier.  You might perhaps use in the header:

```
extern const int array[];
extern const size_t array_size;
```

and where the array is defined:

```
const int array[] = {1, 3, 3, 7};
const size_t array_size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
```

You'd include the header where the array is defined to ensure that the cross-references are correct, in agreement.  You'll get no complaint from me if you choose to use `int` instead of `size_t` (but if you set your compiler to fussy enough, it may have different views on the subject).

Note that the array size is not a 'integer constant' within the meaning of the standard; it could not be used in a `case` label, for example.  If you declare another array using `array_size`, it will be a VLA — variable length array.  Such arrays cannot be declared at file scope (or with `static` storage class inside a function).

See also [How do I use `extern` to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files/1433387#1433387)

#### Illustration

An MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) for the answer:

**`ext-def.h`**

```
#include <stddef.h>

extern const int array[];
extern const size_t array_size;
```

**`ext-def.c`**

```
#include "ext-def.h"

const int array[] = {1, 3, 3, 7};
const size_t array_size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
```

**`ext-use.c`**

```
#include "ext-def.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
        printf("%zu: %d\n", i, array[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

**Compilation**

Using GCC 7.2.0 on a MacBook Pro running macOS High Sierra 10.13.2, using the options specified by [martinkunev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/515212/martinkunev) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999867/extern-declaration-of-array/47999948#comment82968519_47999948):

```
$ gcc -std=c99 -pthread -O2 -fstrict-aliasing -fomit-frame-pointer -pedantic -o ext-def ext-def.c ext-use.c
$ ./ext-def
0: 1
1: 3
2: 3
3: 7
$
```

Using my default compilation options (C11 not C99):

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -c ext-def.c
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -c ext-use.c
$
```

Equally warning-free under either set of options.  You can add `-pedantic` to the C11 command lines without getting any warning, too.

Comment: Can I assume the warning about size is harmless if I never use `sizeof(array)`?

Comment: Which warning are you getting exactly?  (And which compiler options?) . You should never assume warnings are harmless; you should aim to avoid having any compiler warnings showing, precisely so that if one turns up, you treat it as harmful.  C++ compilers have different views about what happens with `const int variable = value;` type notations — they're not globally visible, even without a `static`.

Comment: I compile with `gcc -std=c99 -pthread -O2 -fstrict-aliasing -fomit-frame-pointer -pedantic` and I get `size of symbol array changed from 8 in foo.o to 16 in bar.o` (bar is where the definition of array is)

Comment: I fear you must have done something wrong, then.  I now show in my answer what is necessary — in what's approximately an MCVE.  Without seeing exactly what you did, it is hard to know where you're going wrong.  Note that the header has no initializers in it.

Comment: I figured out what was causing the warning. In the real code the array is of a struct type and in the hurry I was defining the array inside the struct definition (`extern const struct {...} array[];`). When I split them, the warning disappeared.

Comment: That would cause confusion.  You'd need a structure tag, I believe, to achieve the separation properly.  Or a `typedef` for the anonymous structure type.  Glad you managed to resolve it, though; I'd have had a hard time guessing that was the problem from the immediate problem report.

Comment: I was trying to give a minimal example here and apparently it was *too* minimal. If I had pasted the whole code, it would have taken more time for others to read it and I probably would have gotten a ton of comments "you're doing this and that wrong".

Comment: It can be a delicate balancing act.  Consider using just two fields in the structure for an MCVE (unless you're doing a doubly-linked list; then you need 3 — two pointers and an `int` or `char [n]` value).  Something along those lines is sufficient.  Creating an MCVE often involves writing new code parallel to (equivalent to) the real code, masking all the nitty-gritty details of the 'real code' while still getting the compilation warnings/errors.  Ruthless hacking and a good version control system (and a branch) often help.